# I am getting error as pictures show i can not find any solution working with react native react native

Tags: android, react-native, opentok

While creating an archive `libOpentokreatnative.a` is missing in `release-iphoneos`.

I can not find any solution, I have tried removing the library and re-adding it but same the same error is occurring

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

When you are using the [OpenTok React Native](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native) library and archiving the application fails, please do the following:

- In Xcode, go to Target
- Build Phases
- Add OpenTokReactNative under Target Dependencies
- Go to Link Binary with Libraries
- Remove `libOpenTokReactNative.a`
- Add `libOpenTokReactNative.a`